# Split CSV-File by distinct UserId to seperate file

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, awk, scripting

I'm trying to split a csv-file By UserID

```
UserId;FirstName;LastName;Start;End;Type;BreakInMinutes;DateOfCreation;DateOfUpdate
1206;Viktoria;Jechsmayr;2017-10-04 08:15:00.000;2017-10-04 16:15:00.000;work;30;04.10.2017 16:07;05.10.2017 12:31
1205;Brigitte;Jechsmayr;2017-10-05 12:15:00.000;2017-10-05 16:15:00.000;work;0;05.10.2017 12:32;05.10.2017 16:15
1207;Lisa;Jechsmayr;2017-10-06 08:40:00.000;2017-10-06 12:00:00.000;work;0;05.10.2017 15:51;06.10.2017 08:42
1206;Viktoria;Jechsmayr;2017-10-09 08:25:00.000;2017-10-09 16:35:00.000;work;30;09.10.2017 08:23;09.10.2017 16:34
1204;Karl;Jechsmayr;2017-10-11 08:15:00.000;2017-10-11 16:30:00.000;work;60;11.10.2017 08:24;11.10.2017 16:14
1204;Karl;Jechsmayr;2017-10-12 12:30:00.000;2017-10-12 16:45:00.000;work;0;12.10.2017 12:39;12.10.2017 16:43
1205;Brigitte;Jechsmayr;2017-10-13 08:10:00.000;2017-10-13 12:25:00.000;work;0;13.10.2017 08:13;16.10.2017 07:41
1207;Lisa;Jechsmayr;2017-10-16 07:30:00.000;2017-10-16 17:05:00.000;work;30;16.10.2017 07:41;16.10.2017 17:05
```

I'm trying to split the file (>750.000 rows) by the **UserId**-Column (1400 distinct userids).
All Datasets by one UserId should be moved/coppied to a seperate csv-File named like
**UserId_LastName-FirstName.csv**

I don't have any Idea how to do that. I work on a Windows 10 PC.
I tried various scripts found on stackoverflow/google already. Seems not to work:
export generates a ".csv" without a name and 0KB size (empty)
Or it does nothing.

I tried:

```
Import-Csv file.csv | Group-Object -Property "UserId" | 
    Foreach-Object {$path=$_.name+".csv" ; $_.group | 
    Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation}
```

Generates: file with the same content like the Origin but with " at the front and end of each line and filename **.csv** (just extention, no name)

```
awk -F',' 'UserId==NR{a[$1]++;next} a[$1]==1'  file.csv file.csv
```

Output: nothing - no file no error

And some other- I cannot find anymore - sorry.

Thanks for help.

Comment: "Seems not to work..." - in which way? Errors? Partially correct results? Computer catching fire? :) Remember, we can't see your screen

Comment: The scripts I tried "generate" an empty (0KB) file without a name or it does nothing at all.

Comment: Please post the script you are working/trying with, also the error outcome

Comment: Please post output from `Import-Csv file.csv | Select -First 2` so that we can check if import was correct. Perhaps it's matter of delimiter.

Comment: @robdy the output from ```Please post output from Import-Csv file.csv | Select -First 2``` is like seen above. So import is correct

Answer (score 1):

You were close with the `Group-Object`. This should work for you.

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\file.csv' -Delimiter ';' | Group-Object UserId | ForEach-Object {
    $firstName = $_.Group.FirstName | Select-Object -First 1
    $lastName  = $_.Group.LastName  | Select-Object -First 1
    $fileOut   = 'D:\test\{0}_{1}.csv' -f $lastName, $firstName
    $_.Group | Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -NoTypeInformation
}
```